# getting a VBA error 1004 "application defined or object defined error" with copying the files from one worksheet to paste into another

Tags: excel, vba

new to VBA and copying data from one worksheet and posting it into another the user select the source file and it copies the data from the sheet and post it into the destination file where the data values in the source file does not remain the same size

I've tried creating different variable to be used to store the worksheet data but that was unsuccessful and it also said the error was because some data values were protected when I debugged it but I unlocked the sheets and still get the same error

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim source As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    setFile = Application.GetOpenFilename   'used to open the browser window
    tmp = setFile                           'store the selected file in variable tmp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      'preventing long runtimes

    If Dir(tmp) <> "" Then
        Set source = ThisWorkbook     'workbook b1 is declared as the current worksheet opened
        Set destination = Workbooks.Open(tmp)      'the file the user selected is opened in excel
        Set sht1 = destination.Sheets("L1 OVERVIEW")
        Set sht2 = source.Sheets("Overview Paste")
        Set startCell = Range("D5")

        sht1.Activate
        'find last rown and last column
        lastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = sht1.Cells(startCell.Row, sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        sht1.Range(startCell, Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Select   'select range
        sht1.Copy                'copy all the data in selected sheet
        sht2.Range("D5").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        destination.Close True
    Else                                'used to prevent a error message from popping up when the user choose to cancel selecting a file
    End If
End Sub
```

I am expecting the data to be automated where it copies the data from the source worksheet and paste it into the destination worksheet which has all the calculations and cells are in the same order as the values it was copied from. which I could use for simulations

Comment: Probably the error is here: `sht1.Range(startCell, Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Select`. Change that to `sht1.Range(startCell, sht1.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Address).Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("D5")`. You don't need to `Select` here, just define the range and copy it directly.

Comment: You'd better specify where to find your `startCell`. If it's on sht1: `Set startCell = sht1.Range("D5")`